# Create connection based on usb cable between 2 computers

Tags: networking, usb, linux-device-driver

I have 2 linux computers. For security, I want to setup a link between them, then program a library for sending/receiving data over this connection. I know that we can use USB networking cable for connection. But I am not sure is it possible to send and receive data on this link, does it depend on cable manufacturer? And Can I program library without using cable driver?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195765/is-usb-to-usb-data-transfer-between-two-linux-oses-possible

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a USB cable to connect two computers with standard USB interfaces. Standard USB interfaces on computers are *host* interfaces and you can only connect a host to a device, not another host.

Comment: I knew that "USB-USB bridge cable" or "USB Networking cable" can used for sending/receiving file between 2 computers?

Comment: Sure. Basically what they do is make USB look like a network. They're the functional equivalent of two USB Ethernet adapters.

Comment: According to this site: http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/Connecting-Two-PCs-Using-a-USB-USB-Cable/248/1 you can use 2 mode: link mode and network mode, and does not need USB Ethernet adapter.

Comment: Yeah. In link mode it acts kind of like two USB-to-serial adapters connected to each other.

Comment: Can I program library without using cable driver? It hasn't linux driver.

Comment: Stick to something standard, like USB-to-Ethernet adapters.

Answer (score 1):

The "cable" described in the article it's not just a cable, the correct name would be USB host-host bridge controller and it powered by a chip designed and manufactured by [Prolific](http://www.prolific.com.tw/US/index.aspx) - PL 2501. It's described also in the article.

As David Schwarz said with dumb cable (only the wires) you cannot setup a link between two PCs, because USB it's master/slave bus, where a device it's the slave and other the host. The PC it's designed to always be the host (the master).

The response it is that you cannot setup a link or do networking between two PCs using a dumb USB cable. You can do this only using a bridge like the one described in the article.

Comment: In this article, it can transmit data over "cable". So why cannot setup a link?

Comment: The "cable" it's a generic term used in the article referring to that specific product that looks like an USB cable, but it's not actually a simple cable. A simple cable will contain only 4 or 5 wires, while this device contains an electronic device in the middle that it's bridging the data between those two PC. Without that chip it is not going to work. With a simple USB cable you cannot setup a link between two PCs.

Comment: I see. My idea is use this "cable", but don't use it's driver. I will create another program for listening or sending data on the port that this cable plugged.

Comment: I think Linux has support for this USB device. Can you post the USB descriptor? PID, VID, class ID, subclass ID?

Comment: I haven't chosen specific device. First, I want to known is it possible to do.

Comment: So in this case you should rephrase your question: Does Linux (particular distro) have support on the shelf for USB host-host bridge controllers?